# Convert plain string number to decimal with 2 places

Tags: python

I'm using Python3 and I need some help to convert string numbers to decimal with two places:

```
"600000" -> 6000.00
"60000" -> 600.00
"6000" -> 60.00
"600" -> 6.00
"60" -> 0.60
"6" -> 0.06
```

Thanks!

Comment: What is the data type of the numbers you want to convert the strings to?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Convert to float and divide by 100:

```
print '{:.2f}'.format(float(number)/100)
```